# Apache Superset Deck.gl Multiple Layer Map issue

Tags: dictionary, mapbox, apache-superset, deck.gl

I want to create a 4 layered map in apache superset. I tried to use deck.gl multiple layers map. But no matter what dataset I use, the data points are clustered around san francisco and inflexible. Anyone knows how to fix this ? Any suggestions on how to build a layered map in apache superset?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of superset are you using? How are you adding your layers? If you have 4 layers, it means you should have already created say 4 deck.gl charts, stored them, and available for the "deck.gl Multiple Layers" chart. And you simply add them to this chart (see attached where I have three layers already created, named MapABS, mapASR, mapESC)

superset version: 1.2.0rc2
[image]